# If $A$ is orthogonal, for any vector $x$ such that $Ax = b$, $\Vert x \Vert = \Vert b \Vert$

Tags: linear-algebra

Is this statment true: For any vector $x$ such that $Ax = b$, $\Vert x \Vert = \Vert b \Vert$, if $A$ is orthogonal.

I was working on a proof for my linear algebra class, when I noticed that the entire proof could be reduced to simple algebraic work conditional on the following statement being true:

> $$\text{For any vector $x$ such that $Ax = b$, $\Vert x \Vert_2 = \Vert b \Vert_2$, if $A$ is orthogonal.}$$

I have not found a straight answer to this question. I believe the statement is true but I am not sure about how to prove it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Orthogonal matrices essentially represent rotations and reflections, which preserve lengths.

Answer (score 5):

Recall that $A$ is orthogonal if $A^TA = I$. Now look at $\Vert b \Vert_2^2$. Hence, we get that
$$\Vert b \Vert_2^2 = b^Tb = (Ax)^T (Ax) = x^T\underbrace{A^TA}_Ix = x^Tx = \Vert x \Vert_2^2$$

Comment: Thanks, a lot.This is definitely what I was looking for. Now my other proof, related to the least-squares problem, looks much simpler than expected.

Comment: Yes, orthogonal matrices preserve both length and angles. For $Ax\cdot Ay = x\cdot A^TAy = x\cdot y$.

Comment: @TedShifrin: They preserve length only. They are rotation matrices.

Comment: @Serkan: I just wanted to tell him that they do not preserve angles and as a special case of them is rotation matrices.

Comment: @Mhenni Benghorbal OK, there's some serious confusion here. First, orthogonal matrices *do* preserve lengths *and* angles. Second, your statement of the problem *did* assume that $A$ was orthogonal. Third, every rotation matrix *is* orthogonal, but plenty of orthogonal matrices (even with $\det=1$) are *not* rotations once you're in dimension $\ge 4$.